# WiX: new languages for UtilExtension

Tags: wix

in our WiX 3.8 project (creating an MSI) , we'd like to have new languages like es-es, fr-fr, ru-ru, etc.

After adding the files and building I get the following error multiple times saying that the variable is not defined:
"*1>C:\src\wix38\src\ext\UtilExtension\wixlib\UtilExtension.wxs(54,0): error LGHT0102: The localization variable !(loc.msierrXmlFileFailedRead) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.*"

Same error for those variables also: *!(loc.msierrXmlFileFailedOpen)*, *!(loc.msierrXmlFileFailedSelect)*, *!(loc.msierrXmlFileFailedSave)*, *!(loc.msierrSecureObjectsFailedCreateSD)*, *!(loc.msierrSecureObjectsFailedSet)*, *!(loc.msierrSecureObjectsUnknownType)*

So I created a modified version of WiX. I downloaded the sources and added the corresponding language files (*fr-fr.wxl*, *es-es.wxl*, etc) into that folder: *\src\ext\UtilExtension\wixlib*
I also changed *\src\ext\UtilExtension\wixlib\UtilExtension.wixproj* so that it includes those files.
Then I built everything successfully, copied the new files into wix installation directory, restarted visual studio and built again - with exactly the same error.

What did I do wrong?!

Btw: I found a workaround by referencing the new language files (*fr-fr.wxl* etc) in the wixproj file, but I don't see this as a final solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As a solution can be downloaded en-us.wxl language file and modify it any references to your language indicated cultures.

Repository with extension WXL files: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UtilExtension/wixlib

In light pass control these parameters with the path of your file with translation strings: light -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WixFirewallExtension -cultures:pt-br -loc D:\pt-br.wxl ...

Answer (score 0):

I had/have the same problem, some [googling](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/localized-variable-unknown-for-fr-FR-it-IT-and-some-other-cultures-td7585859.html) turned up that the extensions aren't all translated yet.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and maybe my solution will be userfull to somebody.
There is no localization to this variables (msierrXmlFileFailedSelect etc) in fr-fr and es-es cultures, that's the key. You need to find files **UtilExtension_fr-fr.wxl** and **UtilExtension_es-es.wxl** and include them to your project *OR* copy the localization of this variables from this .wxl files to localization files in your project.